# $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!(k+1)}$ sigma sum to equation

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!(k+1)}$$
I tried for this,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}$$
I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Do you realize that $(k+1)k!=(k+1)!$, and $\frac{k+1}{(k+2)!}=\frac{1}{(k+2)k!}$?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!(k+2)}$? Cause that, and not the headline, simplifies into the second thing you wrote. (And has a nice closed form as Durgesh's answer shows.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've taken calculus, you'd know that $\sum_{k=0}^∞ {x^k \over k!} = e^x$.
So, summing $\frac1{k!}\to∞ = e$. Problem is, this includes 1+1... before the actual equation you have. So...

Final answer: $e-2$

Comment: They appear to be asking for a finite sum $\sum_{k=1}^n$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum^{n}_{k=1}\frac{(k+2)-1}{(k+2)!}=\sum^{n}_{k=1}\bigg[\frac{1}{(k+1)!}-\frac{1}{(k+2)!}\bigg]$$